# Why is stat's st_size field offset 96 on 64bit OSX and can it be calculated?

Tags: macos, stat, bsd, darwin

Using the latest sources from [apple's open source repo](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3248.60.10/bsd/sys/stat.h) I have derived the following structure for the "stat" struct (in go syntax):

```
type timespec struct {
    tv_sec      int32
    tv_nsec     uint32
}

type stat64 struct {
    st_dev      int32           /* [XSI] ID of device containing file */
    st_mode     uint16          /* [XSI] Mode of file (see below) */
    st_nlink    uint16          /* [XSI] Number of hard links */
    st_ino      uint64          /* [XSI] File serial number */
    st_uid      uint32          /* [XSI] User ID of the file */
    st_gid      uint32          /* [XSI] Group ID of the file */
    st_rdev     int32           /* [XSI] Device ID */

    st_atimespec        timespec    /* time of last access */
    st_mtimespec        timespec    /* time of last data modification */
    st_ctimespec        timespec    /* time of last status change */
    st_birthtimespec    timespec    /* time of file creation(birth) */

    st_size     int64           /* [XSI] file size, in bytes */
    st_blocks   int64           /* [XSI] blocks allocated for file */
    st_blksize  int32           /* [XSI] optimal blocksize for I/O */
    st_flags    uint32          /* user defined flags for file */
    st_gen      uint32          /* file generation number */
    st_lspare   int32           /* RESERVED: DO NOT USE! */
    st_qspare   [2]int64        /* RESERVED: DO NOT USE! */
}
```

but in practice it turns out st_size has an offset of 96 bytes instead of the 60 shown above. What's the cause of this discrepancy and how can this be seen from the original source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OS X, both fields of `struct timespec` are `long`, which is 64-bit in the usual LP64 convention. Therefore, `sizeof(struct timespec) == 16` (you can check this yourself), and it is aligned on a 64-bit boundary, giving you an offset of 96 for `st_size`.